# How to show that $\sqrt{5}$ is not in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

My strategy is that suppose $\sqrt{5}$ is in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, then it should be of the form $a+b\sqrt{2} +c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}$. After some tedious computation I can get a contradiction. Is there any simpler way to prove this?

Comment: The solution you propose is really not that complicated.

Comment: Can you give me some hint, I am trying to find a way to get a contradiction. @PedroTamaroff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to note that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)$ is a subextension of your extension of degree $2$ over $\Bbb Q$. But one can find out exactly all subextensions of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$ of degree $2$ over $\Bbb Q$, and these are $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2),\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3),\Bbb Q(\sqrt 6)$ (these correspond to the subgroups generated (separately!) by $(1,0),(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ in $C_2\times C_2$. You're now reduced to showing that $\sqrt 5$ lies in none of those, and this is easier.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Actually, the extension obtained by adding to Q square roots of n distinct primes is Galois, with group isomorphic to the direct product of n copies of Z/2Z. But for general n, even "tedious calculation" does not work, you must use properties of primes .